# button vertical align bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align a button in a simple form..

I did this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">teste</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6" style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc;">
                       <label class="form-control"> Teste</label>
                        <input type="button" class="form-control btn-danger" value="example" /><br/>
                         <input type="button" class="form-control btn-danger" value="example" /><br/>
                         <input type="button" class="form-control btn-danger" value="example" /><br/>
                         <input type="button" class="form-control btn-danger" value="example" /><br/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6"  style="margin:0 auto;"  >
                            <input type="button"   value="botão" />
                     </div>
                      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

but I want this button to be centered as shown in the following image:

[image]

how can i do that? i used "style="margin:0 auto;" on div but didn't work..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've made you an example of a possible solution. It may need some extra work but it shows the general idea.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/vG4kP/)

I've added a new class called *vertical-container* for this demo.

```
.vertical-container .row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.vertical-container .row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* float: none;          ~~~~~ Use this setting if needed */
}
```

Comment: Why do we need `float:none;` ?

Comment: @myusuf We don't. Updated. 10x!

Comment: @myusuf @Itay I actually had to add `float: none`. Else, the `display` property was considered by Chrome as `block` instead of `table-cell`. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5.

Comment: @philippe_b Thanks. I guess it depends on the Bootstrap version.  Re-edited my answer